# Don't stop me from creating a similar tag when the tag is new / renaming new tags

Tags: feature-request, support, tags, tag-creation

Somebody on Arqade just created a [windows8] tag. Unfortunately this isn't consistent the other Windows tag, such as [windows-xp] and [windows-7], so I tried renaming it to [windows-8]. Unfortunately the system picked this up and helpfully pointed out that the [windows8] tag already exists - yes, I know that, that's what I'm trying to fix! Now the only way to fix the inconsistent tagging is to remove the tag then wait 24 hours before it is purged from the system and create the new tag again.

Can the system be a bit smarter about the edge cases? There are a few ways to avoid this - disable this feature for when the tag only has a few questions for one will work. Or just add a "are you really very sure you want to do this?" button somewhere where I can click.

Comment: Just curious, have you flagged this for moderator attention?  Moderators are not limited by this and can fix it instantly.

Comment: @casperOne I pinged a mod on chat, and he did it for me, so I suppose that is one way of getting around this

Comment: You can also @ a moderator on the question; moderators always get inbox notifications even if they haven't participated in the comments on the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that for now, the only way to fix these corner cases are to ping or flag for a moderator to come in and fix the posts.

> You can also @ a moderator on the question; moderators always get inbox notifications even if they haven't participated in the comments on the post. – [casperOne♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145607/dont-stop-me-from-creating-a-similar-tag-when-the-tag-is-new-renaming-new-tag#comment416348_145607)

Comment: Side question: As far as I know you can accept your own answer after two days of posting it. Isn't it?

Comment: @hims056 Only for new users. I can't quite remember what the rep threshold is off the top of my head though.

Comment: Oh I found it: [*This can be done no earlier than 48 hours after **the question** is asked*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187824)